# Handle object field on Firestore with Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, object, google-cloud-firestore

Im using Firebase Firestore to save the data of my app. I have an object of objects as field of one of my documents, it looks like this:

[image: it looks like this]

So, there is the language object, which has the field record (Int) and the field daily (Object). The problem its add new data.

I find the way to get this an parsing the data using SwiftJson.

```
let docRef = db.collection("users").document(uid).collection("activities").document(uid)

    docRef.getDocument { (qs, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error retrieving document \(err.localizedDescription)")

        } else {
            if let document = qs {
                let doc = document.data()

                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

                do {
                    let json = try JSON(doc)

                    for i in 0..<json["language"]["daily"].count {
                        print(json["language"]["daily"]["\(i + 1)"]["date"])
                        print(json["language"]["daily"]["\(i + 1)"]["points"])

                    }

                } catch {

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

The plan its saving everyday the points you generate, thats why I have this object. So, the problem is add a new value to the object "daily". How you will do it? or Do you think of another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most NoSQL databases the key to solving a use-case is to find an efficient model to store the data.

In your case, it seems like you want to store the number of points for each data. It also seems that you can only have one number of points for each date.

In that case it makes most sense to use the date as the key for storing the number of points. So in your sample document:

```
language: {
  daily: {
    "2018-03-17": 1200,
    "2018-03-18": 1250
  },
  record: 1120
}
```

The changes I've made (and the reasons):

- By using the date as the key of the daily highscores, the data model can by definition only have a single value for each day. Looking up the highscore for a specific day also becomes easier, since you can determine the direct path to the field once you know the date, instead of having to loop over all dailies.
- I use an [ISO-8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for the dates, which ensures that they can be more easily sorted and filtered.